# Website down because of account throttling

Tags: php, mysql, throttling

I developed a website using PHP and MySQL. The website is being hosted on Bluehost using their Pro plan. The account contains only the website and a vBulletin forum.
It goes down because of account throttling.

Average of concurrent users is 80 - 200

The website was stable and fine for 800 concurrent users in the last month,
but now it's going down for less than 100 users.

Technically I do the following for each page

- Execute about 2-5 select queries (using MySQLi)
- I turn on output buffering ( ob_start() )
- Load a template file for HTML output
- Turn off with clean output buffering ( ob_end_clean() )
- Get the string output and write it to an external file
- If the page gets requested again, I get the output from the file, and I am not doing the above steps

The average page load time before caching the output (in external file) is about 5-10 seconds. After caching the output time is 2-4 seconds

Although there is no heavy usage of the database, my account has been throttled and goes down sometimes.

When I execute "SHOW PROCESSLIST" I get 1 row result

Can I get an advice for this case

Comment: Maybe [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) would be a better place to post this.

Comment: I take it you're paying for this hosting service, seeing I see "Pro plan"? My advice to you; get your money back and find a better host. If my present host were to throttle my account, I'd ditch them in a "New York minute".

Comment: Thank you Fred for advice, I want to make sure that there is no mistake, then I will turned into another host thanks a lot.

Comment: Just to add on real quick, if you are looking for a host I find Digital Ocean to be great. You have full control over everything.

Comment: What you describe is the result on onverloading hostsystems. (IO Load)

Comment: Thank you Christian Gollhardt, I store each HTML page output on a separate file, So every page requested it will be taken from it's cached file, Is this causes throttling when too many different pages requested?